# Set drop down selection in action using value in previous step

Tags: zapier, zapier-cli

I am building a zapier app using the cli.

I have an action, which has a form, with one of it's elements being a drop down, which has a hidden trigger as it's datasource.

With the context of a zap, is it possible to set the selection of the drop down, based on a value from a previous step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team.

You can set a default value for a field, but unfortunately you can't set the value dynamically. The main reason for that is there's a good chance that the trigger your action is paired with won't be one from your app. There could be any any data of any shape coming in, so there's really no way to act directly on it.

​Let me know if you've got any other questions!

**edit**: Even with a dropdown, there's a option to "use a custom value". That's what the users would use if they want to map a value in (or paste it themselves) rather than use the dropdown

Comment: I have an action, which needs an id input that can come from a  triggered result.  So is it ok if I have a version of the action with a basic input and a version with a dropdown?  Your docs say that id fields should have a dropdown, but in this case I need both

Comment: Even with a dropdown, there's a option to "use a custom value". That's what the users would use if they want to map a value in (or paste it themselves) rather than use the dropdown.

Comment: Thanks @xavdid ! I didn't know that was available!